# Document with each word having overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there a possibility to make each word in my beamer presentation come after a click without adding `\pause` before each word?

Comment: another approach using the `animate` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81850/36296

Answer (score 4):

> based on an answer by @egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250559/36296

The following could be used in `fragile` beamer frames. Please don't complain if it breaks other stuff :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\AND}{%
  \hskip\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
  \pause
  }

\newenvironment{pausespaces}
 {\par\obeyspaces\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\AND}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{pausespaces}%
some text some text someveryverylongword text text
\end{pausespaces}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250559/4427 ?

Comment: @samcarter It has some problem with blocks in beamer.  Please check my file https://pastebin.com/1R7UFRaW

Comment: @supremum As I said: don't complain if it breaks stuff :)

Comment: @supremum And don't load `enumitem` with beamer

Comment: @supremum And don't use two-letter font commands, use `\textbf{...}` instead

Comment: @supremum And don't use \\ for new lines

Comment: @supremum If I move the `pausespaces` environment inside the block it works fine. (IMHO uncovering large portions of text word by word is a bad idea)

Comment: @samcarter Thanks, should I use \newline instead of \\?

Comment: @supremum In most situations: just use an empty line