# Is There a Proper Place to Put Indexing Syntax in the Code?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, luatex, indexing, white-space

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

This is a sentence. This is another \textbf{sentence}.   \textbf{This} is too a sentence.

\vspace*{15pt}

This is a sentence. This is another \textbf{sentence}. \index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! An index entry with a lot of words.} \index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! A different index entry with some more words.} \textbf{This} is too a sentence. This is another sentence. This is a sentence.

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with the first page of output:

[image]

Notice the (expected) proper horizontal spacing between the sentences in the first paragraph, even though in the code I had inserted extra spaces between the second and third sentences.

*Remark:* If I had inserted in the code, say, ten extra spaces between the said sentences, I would expect the same output.

Now, look at the output of the second paragraph---and in particular---the extra horizontal space that has been inserted between the second and third spaces. The difference in the code is---that I have inserted a couple of index commands, which, many times, appears to have no affect on the horizontal spacing between two consecutive sentences at all.

But here, it does.

QUESTION: Can anyone tell me what might be causing this unwanted phenomenon and is there a remedy  for it? Perhaps, more importantly, is there a proper way to insert indexing code? Is it O.K. to leave a space between two consecutive index commands or should they be inserted consecutively without interruption as in one long command?

*Note:* I have added the bold for visual emphasis. The described phenomenon occurs whether or not bold is used. I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: `\index` should normally be placed attached to the word you want to index, for a couple of reasons; one is to avoid unwanted spaces.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. Also, if I may, should two consecutive indices `\index{}` and `\index{}` be coded `\index{}` `\index{}` or `\index{}\index{}`? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Same problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing you observe doesn't depend on the long index entries, but just on the fact that spaces around `\index{...}` *count* as spaces in output.

I reuse [code by Marcin Woliński](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44951/4427) which allows to show spaces in order to illustrate what happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\AND}{\unskip
  \hskip 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
  \cleaders\copy\ANDbox\hskip\wd\ANDbox
  \hskip 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
  \ignorespaces}
\newsavebox\ANDbox
\sbox\ANDbox{\textbullet}


\begin{document}

\catcode` =\active
\let =\AND

This is a sentence. %
This is another \textbf{sentence}. %
\textbf{This} is too a sentence.

\vspace*{15pt}

This is a sentence. %
This is another \textbf{sentence}. \index{a} \textbf{This} is too a sentence. %
This is another sentence. This is a sentence.

\vspace*{15pt}

This is a sentence. %
This is another \textbf{sentence}. \index{b} \index{c} \textbf{This} is too a sentence. %
This is another sentence. This is a sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that in the second paragraph there are two spaces, due to a single `\index` command, and in the third paragraph there are three.

So, first of all, ***no spaces*** between the word to index and the `\index` command. Consider also that a space would allow a line break, which in turn could allow a page break and you'd find the index entry referring to a *different* page than the word it points to.

What's the best position of `\index`? In front of the word you want to index, which also has the benefit of disallowing hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\AND}{\unskip
  \hskip 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
  \cleaders\copy\ANDbox\hskip\wd\ANDbox
  \hskip 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
  \ignorespaces}
\newsavebox\ANDbox
\sbox\ANDbox{\textbullet}


\begin{document}

\catcode` =\active
\let =\AND

This is a sentence. %
This is another \textbf{sentence}. %
\textbf{This} is too a sentence.

\vspace*{15pt}

This is a sentence. %
This is another \index{a}\textbf{sentence}. \textbf{This} is too a sentence. %
This is another sentence. This is a sentence.

\vspace*{15pt}

This is a sentence. %
This is another \index{b}\index{c}\textbf{sentence}. \textbf{This} is too a sentence. %
This is another sentence. This is a sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In tough paragraphing cases, you can decide what to do, maybe using

```
\index{entry}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}longwordwithindexthatmustbehyphenated
```

Example:

```
Wordthatcanbehyphenated wordthatcanbehyphenated
\index{entry}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}longwordwithindexthatmustbehyphenated
wordthatcanbehyphenated
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @egreg for this very helpful and informative answer.